fatal: cannot lock ref "refs/heads test/hotfix refs/heads/test' exists;cannot create refs/heads/test/hotfix
When I tried to checkout test/hotfix branch from test branch:
git checkout -b test/hotfix

shows error:
fatal: cannot lock ref "refs/heads test/hotfix refs/heads/test' exists;cannot create refs/heads/test/hotfix

I have checked the local branch like this:
-> git branch
develop
develop_zxg
feature/jxq_order
jiangxiaoqiang/order
master
test

there is no test/hotfix branch. I also have tried this command:
git update-ref -d refs/heads/origin/branch

still did not fixed this issue. does anyone facing the same issue?

issue:
There is a small gotcha in branch naming: git has actual files on your filesystem(*) to represent the branches (check tree .git/refs/heads to have a view of that), and you can't have a file and a directory with the same name.
This is reflected in the naming rules for your branches: you can't have a branch named test and a branch named test/hotfix at the same time.
(fwiw: the same holds for tags, remote branches ...)

fix:
Get rid of your test branch (delete it, or rename it: git branch -m test test-mine or git branch -m test test/mine), or choose another name for your test/hotfix branch.

(*) it is not entirely true that branches (and refs in general) are always represented by individual files on disk, git will also pack them in a .git/packed-refs file (see git help pack-refs) and may delete the individual files. But git still enforces the naming rule: the ref names should be compatible with having them as files and directories on disk.
